# Css won't work on my div

Tags: css, html

My CSS effects the background but will not affect my `<div>`.  What am i doing wrong?  Could not get it to work copying and pasting from another site.  Why is it ignoring my `<div>` but the background still works.  trying `<div class="">` too

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<p> 12.25.13 </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
#main {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 200px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #B7DEF3;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have other CSS for `p` that's overriding it?

Comment: thats my entire css file but i will try it

Comment: Just checking:  the last seven lines of what you pasted are what's in `main.css`, right?  Not pasted at the end of your HTML file?

Comment: If one of these answers is correct please mark it as answer so other people with this issue can easily find an answer to their question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with it? I putted your issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUAnx/), but couldn't find any errors. It's just working how it supposed to be.

Please explain your problem in more detail if the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUAnx/) is not what you wanted to achieve.

Nothing wrong with this:

```
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #B7DEF3;
}
```

You probably misspelled the filename or the path to the file is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's with your filename or a mis-spelling somewhere in your code, since it works ok for other users, as well as for me.